# What's the best way to write some semaphore-like code in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, parallel-processing

Suppose I have a function `f` which takes an integer argument. `f` may not terminate on some arguments, but its result is equally valuable. (For concreteness, the argument could be the seed to a random number generator, which is passed to a SAT solver.)

I want to use concurrency and invoke `f 1`, `f 2`, `f 3`, etc., and return when the first one finishes. So, each thread should be running code that looks like

```
comp <- start_proc (f 1)
wait(comp || anyDone) -- wait for _either_ of these signals to be true
if comp then
    set anyDone = True
```

What's the easiest way to do this? The AMB operator comes to mind, but I'd need to run all processes simultaneously (e.g. on a 24- or 80-core machine). (Distributed computing solutions would be even better.) A superficial look at the [AMB wiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Amb) suggests it may not support non-terminating processes?

### test

Currently, I'm not getting the answers to work with what I want. I think this is probably more of an issue with how I'm creating processes than anything else.

Define

```
runProc (x:xs) =
    createProcess (proc x xs) >>= \(_, _, _, h) -> waitForProcess h
```

Then, I want to race `runProc ["zsh", "-c", "sleep 3"]` and `runProc ["ls"]`. I modified Thomas' answer a little, but it didn't work.

```
raceL :: [IO α] -> IO α
raceL ops = do
    mv <- newEmptyMVar
    tids <- forM ops (\op -> forkIO (op >>= putMVar mv))
    answer <- takeMVar mv
    mapM_ killThread tids
    return answer
```

Compiling with `-threaded` and running with `+RTS -N` (I have a 4-core machine) doesn't seem to help.

Comment: It appears that `killThread` (which operates by throwing an asynchroneous exception to the thread to be killed), does not interrupt `waitForProcess`. This could be because the exception is getting masked. However, even if this _did_ work, it would only kill the thread, not the process.

Comment: You might want to check out [Orc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/orc), a DSL library for orchestrating parallel tasks, and dealing with things like races and killing off the threads that didn't make it. The Hackage documentation is rather thin, though, so I recommend watching the [presentation](http://vimeo.com/16753072) or reading [the paper](http://code.galois.com/paper/2010/Hask-Orc-DRAFT.pdf) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of amb, consider [unamb](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb)! It provides a handful of nice primitives for racing computations, both pure and impure. For example:

```
Prelude Data.Unamb> unamb (last [1..]) 32
32
Prelude Data.Unamb> race (threadDelay 5000000 >> return 3) readLn
Prelude Data.Unamb Control.Concurrent> race (threadDelay 5000000 >> return 3) readLn
56
56
Prelude Data.Unamb Control.Concurrent> race (threadDelay 5000000 >> return 3) readLn
3
```

Comment: Looks like there's something weird with `race` for pure computations. `race (return 32) (return $ last [1..])` freezes for me (reversing the order works).`

Comment: I'm having some trouble with IO's too. Define `runProc (x:xs) =
    createProcess (proc x xs) >>= \(_, _, _, h) -> waitForProcess h`, then `race (runProc ["zsh", "-c", "sleep 3"]) (runProc ["ls"])` does not exit when "ls" finishes.

Comment: @gatoatigrado: Both of those terminated properly for me when I added `+RTS -N2` to my ghci command line. It wouldn't surprise me if `last [1..]` gets optimized to a loop that does no allocation (and hence never offers an opportunity to switch green threads). Not sure about the other one though.

Comment: They both terminate for me too, but it should terminate immediately, not after the "sleep 3" finishes. This probably has more to do with how creating processes works... thanks!

Comment: @gatoigrado: Running `race (runProc ["zsh", "-c", "sleep 3"]) (runProc ["ls"])` immediately prints the contents of my directory, returns `ExitSuccess`, and dumps me back to the ghci prompt. There is no 3-second delay. This seems like the desired behavior to me. Just to double-check: when you test, are you running ghci with `+RTS -N2` as I suggested in my comment?

Comment: I've been running the binary with `+RTS -N2`. Appending that to the `ghci` command, i.e. `ghci Test.hs +RTS -N2` didn't seem to help either. I'm using GHC 7.0.4 on Linux (x86_64). To be precise, here is the code and command line: http://pastebin.com/FkawhS3j . Thanks for your help.

Comment: @gatoigrado: Hm, seems like a bug in 7.0.3. I can reproduce in 7.0.3, but not in GHC HEAD. So upgrading (eventually) should solve your problem.

Comment: @DanielWagner let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3013/discussion-between-gatoatigrado-and-daniel-wagner)

Answer (score 8):

Why not just an `MVar` and `forkIO`?

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import System.Environment
import Control.Monad

main = do
  mv <- newEmptyMVar
  [nrThreads] <- liftM (map read) getArgs
  tids <- replicateM nrThreads (forkIO $ operation mv)
  answer <- takeMVar mv
  mapM_ killThread tids

operation :: MVar Int -> IO ()
operation mv = putMVar mv 5
```

This will fork `nrThreads` light weight threads.  Once one thread has finished it should place the answer in the provided MVar.  All other threads will then be killed by the main thread.  No explicit polling is needed as the GHC RTS will reschedule `main` once the `MVar` becomes non-empty.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use [STM](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Software_transactional_memory) to detect termination, then explicitly kill all other threads. We can define:

```
start_proc :: IO a -> IO (ThreadId, TVar (Maybe a))

start_proc job = do
  resultVar <- newTVarIO Nothing
  forkIO $ job >>= (atomically . writeTVar resultVar)
  return resultVar
```

Then do:

```
any_parallel :: [IO a] -> IO a
any_parallel jobs = do
  (threads, vars) <- liftM unzip $ mapM start_proc jobs
  result <- atomically $ foldl orElse retry (map check_job vars)
  mapM_ killThread threads
  return result
  where
    check_job :: TVar (Maybe a) -> STM a
    check_job resultVar = do
      val <- readTVar resultVar
      case val of
        Nothing -> retry
        Just x  -> return x
```

The key thing here is, the first time run_multiple goes through its set of result variables, they're all `Nothing`, and so it `retry`s. The STM monad records which `TVar`s it looked at, and whenever any of them is written, the STM transaction is re-executed. At this point, it sees one of the `TVar`s is not `Nothing`, and can take the result at that point.

Once we have a result, of course, we simply terminate all threads. This is likely to be faster than having them check in their inner loop for some shared flag; there's less contention on a shared MVar (or what-have-you).

Note that `killThread` waits for the target thread to reach a 'safe point' (ie, memory allocation) before killing the thread. This cannot be guaranteed to occur if the target thread has a tight inner loop that does not perform any memory allocation. You may want to make sure the threads periodically perform an `IO` action that forces allocation to occur.

Comment: Is a periodic IO action really less of a bottleneck than a periodic check on a shared flag?

Comment: @Owen, it depends on how long-running these actions are. N killThreads vs N*M readIOVar right in your inner loop, after all. You could also punt the killThreads into a new background thread (ie, `forkIO $ mapM_ killThread threads`)

Comment: I'm talking about "You may want to make sure the threads periodically perform an IO action that forces allocation to occur." Is there any reason that checking a flag would have to occur more frequently?

Comment: @Owen, Most computations will end up making some degree of allocations anyway, so with killThread you get the check for free. It's only if you, by some miracle, have some _really_ tight inner loop that this would be a problem.

Comment: This is just unnecessary complication.  Use an `MVar`.

Comment: @augustss, Doesn't a MVar require acquiring a lock when examining it?

Comment: Or, for that matter, bouncing a cache line between physical CPUs

Comment: @bdonlan You create an empty MVar, then have all the processes doing a put and then main process doing a take.  When the main process gets the value it kills all the other processes.

Comment: @augustss, yes, I was concerned that might result in cache line bouncing, but on further reflection, I see your point

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to manually schedule your code by using [a monad to model steps of computation](https://gist.github.com/1177192).

This can let you manually switch between different computation threads, stepping each a few at a time,
until one of them finishes:

```
sum5 :: [ Computation (Int, Int) ]
sum5 = [ sum5' x 0 | x <- [ 0, 1.. ] ]
  where sum5' x y = if x + y == 5
                      then return (x,y)
                      else do 
                        y' <- return (y+1) 
                        sum5' x y'

prod6 :: [ Computation (Int, Int) ]
prod6 = [ prod6' x 0 | x <- [ 0, 1.. ] ]
  where prod6' x y = if x * y == 6
                      then return (x,y)
                      else do 
                        y' <- return (y+1) 
                        prod6' x y'

firstSolution :: [Computation a] -> Strategy a -> a
firstSolution cs s = head . toList . runComputation $ s cs
```

Then you can see how allow you to interleave computations (even non terminating ones)

```
ghci> firstSolution sum5 fair
(5,0)
ghci> firstSolution sum5 diagu
(0,5)
ghci> firstSolution sum5 diagd
(5,0)
ghci> firstSolution prod6 fair
^CInterrupted.
ghci> firstSolution prod6 diagu
(2,3)
ghci> firstSolution prod6 diagd
(3,2)
```